# ¿Cómo funcionan las bases de datos MDF en c#?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, asp.net, windows-forms, entity-framework

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual tengo una base de datos en MDF(base de datos basada en servicio), y al trabajar con ella tengo un problema, o bueno creo no saber bien como funciona.

Esta es mi DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar la sentencia `select * from Usuarios` me retorna lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si ejecuto la sentencia `update Usuarios set Usuario = 'juan' where Id = 1` dice que afecto la fila correctamente y al consultarlo de nuevo sale bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando ejecuto el proyecto y agrego nuevos registros, estos cambios no se ven reflejados.

Aquí acabo de agregar un registro en la tabla Ventas y se puede ver en la lista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si ejecuto `select * from Ventas` no me aparece el nuevo registro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe por que puede pasar esto?

Estoy usando Entity Framework, un proyecto en capas en .NetFramework 4.7.2, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Aquí está el código que estoy usando para guardar los registros:

```
public bool Save(Ventas venta)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new VentasDBEntities())
            {
                db.Ventas.Add(venta);
                db.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var item in venta.DetalleVenta)
                {
                    item.Id_Venta = venta.Id;
                    db.DetalleVenta.Add(item);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Y esta es la clase que estoy usando para crear esa base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deberias agregar el codigo

Comment: Pon el codigo q tienes

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el código, muchas gracias

Comment: mdf, sera una base sql express? y estas mirando la misma base en todos los casos? porque al ser una base de archivo unico, tu programa puede que este usando otra base distinta al ejecutarse....

Comment: Al crearla me dice que es una "Base de datos orientada a servicios"

Answer (score -1):

**Esto sucede porque al momento de ejecutar tu proyecto se crea automáticamente una copia del archivo mdf en la capeta BIN del proyecto**, es por ello que no puedes ver los cambios en la bd original. es decir, tus cambios están en el archivo mdf de la carpeta BIN de tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]